# Postsgresql Outer Join not working as intended

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

A seemingly simple query that I can't make work...

Two tables room and availability

```
Room         [id, title, beds]
Availability [room_id, date, bed_delta]
```

A Room has a fixed, maximum number of beds available. Availability describes periods during which `Room.beds` is modified (up or down).

I am trying to construct a query that, for a given room and a given start date and duration will sum the beds available.

For example:

- Room 1 usually has 2 beds
- For 1 hour, 1 bed is taken
- The expected result is 1

If another period of availability is added that overlaps this datetime range and further reduces the beds by 1, the expected result is 0.

It feels like a relatively simple query:

- LEFT OUTER JOIN Room to Availability on room_id
- Constrain by date
- Select Room.beds - sum(Availability.bed_delta)

i.e.

```sql
SELECT r.beds - coalesce(sum(a.bed_delta), 0) as beds_free
FROM room r
LEFT OUTER JOIN availability a ON (r.id = a.room_id)
WHERE date = '2012-01-01 09:00:00+01:00'
AND r.id = 2
GROUP BY r.id;
```

This query only returns if there is a matching row in `availability`. What I expected was a single row for the room with id == 2.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is this part of your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE date = '2012-01-01 09:00:00+01:00'
```

An outer join only "allows" rows for which the *join condition* (here, `r.id = a.room_id`) fails; other constraints on the right-hand table that are imposed in the `WHERE` clause can still exclude entire rows from the result.  Yeah, it's tricky.

Solution: move the `date` constraint into the join condition:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN availability a ON (r.id = a.room_id AND date = '2012-01-01 09:00:00+01:00')
```

(Yes, surprisingly enough you can stick arbitrary conditions in there, and as you're now discovering, (for outer joins) this can be necessary!)

Alternatively, you could you use a correlated subquery to find the sum of all the `Availability` records that match the `Room` of interest:

```
SELECT r.beds - coalesce((
    SELECT sum(a.bed_delta)
    FROM availability a
    WHERE a.room_id = r.id
    AND date = '2012-01-01 09:00:00+01:00'
), 0) as beds_free
FROM room r
WHERE r.id = 2;
```

I find subqueries to be easier to understand than `GROUP`ed outer joins, but YMMV.

Comment: Cheers, very useful. I'm afraid I'm tainted by years of MySQL use. Any comment on the performance implications of a correlated subquery?

Comment: You're welcome.  There's no hard and fast rule about performance anymore that I'm aware of.  The query planner will consider many different possible plans, and knows many ways to convert queries into other equivalent queries, so it may well produce the same query plan for both.  Use `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see what it thinks is best.

Comment: @RobCowie If this answer was correct as you expected means please accept the answer this may helpful to others too.

Comment: The fact that the interpreter would allow you to negate the OUTER JOIN is so stupid. It should throw a warning or error. This has stumped me for years.